# ImageMagick - convert RGB to BT.601 and BT.709 result the same

Tags: imagemagick

I use below bash script to convert RGB to YCbCr601 and YCbCr709 on MacOsx, but the result is the same:

```
PNGNAME="input.png"
YUVNAME="image.yuv"
YUVNAME709="image709.yuv"
OUTNAME="result.png"
W=8
H=8
convert -size ${W}x${H} xc:#008800 $PNGNAME

convert $PNGNAME -depth 8 -colorspace Rec601YCbCr yuv:$YUVNAME

echo "601"
od -v -t u1 $YUVNAME 

convert $PNGNAME -depth 8 -colorspace Rec709YCbCr yuv:$YUVNAME709
echo "709"
od -v -t u1 $YUVNAME709
```

Output:

```
601
0000000    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000020    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000040    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000060    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000100    82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82
0000120    71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71
0000140
709
0000000    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000020    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000040    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000060    80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80
0000100    82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82  82
0000120    71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71  71
0000140
```

Comment: I don't think your code is correct. How did you run it? I believe `bash` would treat `#008800` and everything following it as a comment.

Comment: Also, I think ImageMagick converts back to `601` the moment you prefix the output file with `yuv:`.

Comment: But it really works on my macosx! the only issue is 601 and 709 output the same result!

Answer (score 2):

I think **ImageMagick** is doing the colourspace conversion correctly, and you will see that if you run these two commands:

```
convert -depth 8 xc:'#008800' -colorspace Rec601YCbCr txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,rec601ycbcr
0,0: (20510.2,21189.7,18134)  #505247  rec601ycbcr(80,82,71)

convert -depth 8 xc:'#008800' -colorspace Rec709YCbCr txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,rec709ycbcr
0,0: (24996.2,19296.5,16894.4)  #614B42  rec709ycbcr(97,75,66)
```

The issue is that when you specify the output as `yuv:FILENAME`, that causes an implicit colourspace conversion back to `Rec601`, regardless of what it is at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, so no way to save it to yuv file? and how can I convert yuv back to rgb? I try below command 'convert -depth 8 -colorspace Rec709YCbCr xc:'#614b42' -colorspace RGB txt:' but output is 'rgb(30,18,14)'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to convert to YCbCr only to revert back to RGB. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I just want to verify how much data will be lost between different conversion!